# Firebase app distribution fails: invalid apk file

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-distribution

I'm trying to upload an apk for distribution on firebase but I get this error instead:

**"There's been an error processing your distribution. Ensure you're uploading a valid IPA or APK and try again. Additional information about this error: Invalid APK file."**

I'm indeed trying to upload an apk (which by the way, works fine on device). I thought the issue could be related to the android keystore, but that seems okay too. Can't find much more info on this online. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using fastlane to upload app OR doing manually on firebase app distribution ?

Comment: I'm uploading manually on firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be various reasons for this type of issue and you can try the below methods to solve the problem.

1. Try to upload apk via a google chrome OR any other browser. Reason for saying this is sometime problem is your session invalid. Using any different browser such as firefox,IE etc. would create new session and allow to upload apk.
2. Sometimes it happens due to low internet speed speed but it's rare.
3. It could be happened with the application icon. You must need to be set in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file
4. You can contact to firebase support team if above doesn't work. [Link](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact?visit_id=637653965604813284-1515560290&rd=1)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Changing browser to Safari actually did the trick for me.

Comment: Glad to heard that it help you.